# How to set data-off message as blank instead of "off", in bootstrap switch?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

Below is the code snippet of my bootstarp toggle button. Here I have set the data-off as blank string although its showing message as off. How can I set it as blank string ?

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="CPSoutfrtuc2-chk" value="1" id="CPSoutfrtuc2-chk" data-style="wmwa" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="PO" data-off="" data-size="mini">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that I have set `data-off = "&nbsp;"` instead of blank string and its working. May be it will helpful to someone else also. Below is the code snippet.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="CPSoutfrtuc2-chk" value="1" id="CPSoutfrtuc2-chk" data-style="wmwa" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="PO" data-off="&nbsp;" data-size="mini">
```